# Missing DPad functionality

Tags: android

My Tv app rejected by play store.
Reason is => Your app requires user interaction for menus or app navigation. Please make sure that menus and app navigation needed for the app’s core functionality are fully functional using a DPad. Please refer to our DPAD Control and Hardware Declaration documentation.

**But i have tested on emulator and on real TV DEVICE it is working fine and control by remote is also working.**

I am implemented the D-pad functionality only on video player screen, not on other screen.

```
override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE) {

        if (simpleExoplayer!!.isPlaying) {
            simpleExoplayer!!.pause()
        } else {
            simpleExoplayer!!.play()
        }
        return true
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT) {
          simpleExoplayer!!.seekTo(simpleExoplayer!!.getCurrentPosition() + 1000)

        return true
    }else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT) {

            simpleExoplayer!!.seekTo(simpleExoplayer!!.getCurrentPosition() - 1000)

        return true
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
}
```

[Manifest file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlV5V.png)

Please help me.

Comment: Unclear if you read/are following: https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/navigation  and https://developer.android.com/design/ui/tv/guides/styles/focus-system

Comment: Is it required in every screen of the app? In my app there is four screen . 1)Splash screen 2) Detail screen where video list is showing 3) Video player screen.                              NOTE ( I am implemented the D-pad functionality only on video player screen)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it required in every screen of the app?

Any TV app screen that requires user input requires D-pad support.

> In my app there is four screen . 1)Splash screen 2) Detail screen where video list is showing 3) Video player screen. NOTE ( I am implemented the D-pad functionality only on video player screen)

You say "four screen" but then only listed three. A splash screen normally does not require user input. However, your other two screens do, and you need to support D-pads for that user input on both screens.